# The Microsoft.Eventhub Resource provider in my subscription has a perpetual status of registering

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-subscription

The Microsoft.Eventhub Resource provider in my subscription has a perpetual status of registering and I'm not sure why. For some reason all of my subscriptions are in this same perdicument and I'm certain why. I attempted to unregister then reregister Microsoft.Eventhub RP but I continued to see the same status.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some providers may take time to be registered .Otherwise, there may be service health issues in the middle of process affecting the registration process.

Also as you said you have multiple subscriptions in the tenant and the current subscription is not the right one which the user has the right permission.

Make sure to have contributor or owner permissions to register in the particular subscription.

[image]

**`az login`**

**`az account set --subscription subscription_id`**
and set correct credentials .

```
provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = "..."
  client_id       = "..."
  client_secret   = "..."
  tenant_id       = "..."
}
```

[image]

If you don't use the specified terraform resource you can s[kip provider registration.](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs#skip_provider_registration)

```
provider "azurerm" {
  skip_provider_registration = true
}
```

Also  upgrade terraform according to working provider versions  and azurerm provider .In some versions the provider may be deprecated and not compatible with our terraform provider version.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      version = "~> 2.29.0"
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Also check [Terraform - Azure as a provider and limited access account | StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57892557/terraform-azure-as-a-provider-and-limited-access-account)